# Error bar information not displaying in Scatter3d hover

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have a 3d plot working with z_axis asymmetrical error bars, but when I hover over the data points, I'm only getting the `(x,y,z)` information instead of `(x,y,z +err/-err)`.

[Plotly documentation for the error bars](https://plot.ly/python/error-bars/) indicates that this information should be automatically included in the hover label. I tried using the `hovertext` attribute (setting `hoverinfo='text'` per the [Scatter3d docs](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#scatter3d-hovertext)) with no success. Perhaps my attempt at reformatting labels isn't in the format that plotly requires, but I've tried a few different ways now to no avail. Below is the code trying to use the `hovertext` and `hoverinfo` attributes.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import iplot, init_notebook_mode
import cufflinks as cf

cf.go_offline()
cf.set_config_file(world_readable=True,theme='pearl',offline=True)
init_notebook_mode()

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [1,2,3,4,5]
z1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
z2 = np.multiply(z1,2)
z3 = np.multiply(z1,0.5)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':x,'B':y,'C':z1,'D':z2,'E':z3})
test = []
for row in df.values:
    test.append('x:{}; y:{}; z={} +{}/-{}'.format(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4]))

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter3d(
        x=x, 
        y=y, 
        z=z1, 
        # https://plot.ly/python/reference/#scatter3d-error_z
        error_z = dict( 
            visible=True,
            type='data',
            array=np.subtract(z2,z1),
            arrayminus=np.subtract(z1,z3)
        ), 
        name='Test Plot',
        marker=dict(size=4),
        opacity = 1, # 1=default
        mode='markers',
        hovertext=test,
        hoverinfo='text' # set this to 'text' if using 'hovertext' attr        
    )
)

fig.layout.update(scene = dict(
        xaxis_title='X Axis',
        yaxis_title='Y Axis',
        zaxis_title='Output')
)

fig.show()
```

Comment: There is a syntax error on line 8. Also I am missing information to help you. Include the packages you are importing and add all the objects you are using (sim_returns is not defined for example)

Comment: @DZurico Sorry about that - I just updated the code and included a change that I made this morning (changing the `hovertext` variable to a 1-dim array and changing each array entry to a string type). I'm still confused as to why the plot doesn't seem to be doing this automatically, since I don't want to have to do this every time.

Comment: This may just be a bug/shortcoming in Plotly.js. I've filed an issue here: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/4133